# GNOME Desktop: Shortcut to move window to "the next screen"

Tags: gnome, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-tweaks

In the Unity desktop (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04) it is possible to create a shortcut (with a Unity tweaking tool) to move the selected window to "the next screen" (or "the other screen").
By "the next screen" I mean that if you arrange the available screens in a circle, the shortcut will move the window to the next screen in the circle (always in the same direction).

As opposed to the closest alternative that exists in the built-in Ubuntu keyboard shortcut settings, that allows the setting of two shortcuts: one for moving the window to the right, and the other for moving the window to the left.
For example, if the window is already on the right screen, then the "move to the right" shortcut will do nothing.

The "move window to the next screen" is especially useful in case that there are only two screens, since this shortcut will always move the window to the other screen, without the need to think whether the movement is to the right or to the left.

**Is there a way in the GNOME desktop, specifically in Ubuntu 22.04, to have such a "move window to the next screen" shortcut?**

Or, is there a way in the GNOME desktop to make the existing built-in shortcuts move in a circular way?

I have tried the "GNOME Tweaks" application (formerly known as "GNOME Tweak Tool") but could not see any such option there.

Answer (score 4):

I found this link
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>: Move the current window one monitor to the left.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>: Move the current window one monitor to the right.